# How to process a String with an unknown unit as weighed object

Tags: java, android, string, substring, string-parsing

I have to process the data received from a database where all values are numbers with many different units

for example

```
12.553 mg
23floz
5 oz
23kg
45 kg
```

etc

To process these data I have to convert everything as a custom object `Quantity(double amount, String unit)`

**THE PROBLEM**

I don't know how many kinds of units there are in the database, I need a way that cut the numeric part of the data from the unit and keep these separately in 2 temp String so after that I process the data I could istanciate a Quantity object correctly

The values not always contains whitespaces that separe the number from the unit, therefore solution like

```
String[] tmp = line.split("\\s");
Quantity(Double.parse(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
```

Unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reading data line by line, splitting each line on space and using each part as `Quantity` argument? Something like:

```
String[] tmp = line.split("(?<=\\d)\\s*(?=[a-zA-Z])");
Quantity(Double.parse(tmp[0]), tmp[1]);
```

this will split on place that has zero or more whitespaces surrounded from left side with digit and from right with chracter from range a-z or A-Z

---

Demo:

```
String[] lines = { "12.553 mg", "23floz", "5 oz", "23kg", "45 kg", };
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] tmp = line.split("(?<=\\d)\\s*(?=[a-zA-Z])");
    System.out.println(tmp[0] + ":" + tmp[1]);
}
```

output:

```
12.553:mg
23:floz
5:oz
23:kg
45:kg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give me more details about line.split("\\s"); ? If the numerc parts is 23 and if is 45.7(with decimal) always split the two parts separately? In addiction many values are something like 46.86grams, this method works only on the blank spaces?

Comment: @AndreaF split uses regex as its argument and in regex `\s` represents any whitespace so for data like `"12.553 mg"` `split("\\s")` will produce array `["12.553","mg"]`. I assumed each of your lines will be in format `numberSpaceUnit` so decided to split in on each space. If there can be any other cases you probably should edit your question and include them.

Comment: ok I have edited the question, thanks for the answer, but unfortunately not always there are whitespaces

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use regular expression matching to do this.

```
    String example = "12.564mg";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9.]+)\\s*([a-zA-Z]+)");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(example);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        new Quantity(Double.valueOf(matcher.group(1)), matcher.group(2));
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't parse: " + example);
    }
```

You can store the `Pattern` and re-use it for each item of input to parse.  Also, this is a little safer than splitting because `matcher.matches()` will allow you to check that the parse was successful and allow you to avoid an unexpected `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.